# Mapping points to grid to plot density on a map

Tags: r, heatmap, rgdal

I have a dataset of 900K randomly sampled coordinate points with a value associated with each point. I want to make a grid on the map and assign each cell the avg value of all the points that lie within the cell. Finally I want to plot the grid as a heatmap.

The resolution of the grid could be 100 sq. km. cell upto 10000 sq km.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your syntax in calling `autoKrige` is not correct, it should be:

```
kr <- autoKrige(mean_week1~1,project_df)
```

The `formula` argument never contains a vector, it always contains column names from the attributes in `project_df`.

`autoKrige` can predict on any `Spatial*` object, e.g. `SpatialGrid` or `SpatialPoints`, simply pass the object you want to predict on to the `new_data` argument of `autoKrige`. So, if you want to predict on irregular points, simply create a `SpatialPoints` object with the locations and pass it to `autoKrige`.

In regard to calculation time, 900.000 points is a large dataset. You can limit the amount of data that is used for predictions by using the `nmax` (max number of points used) or the `maxdist` (maximum distance up to which points are used) arguments. These are part of the `...`, and are passed on to `krige` from the `gstat` package.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra..Thanks for the info. So I am actually interested in getting a grid from the 900K points and then making a raster from that grid. When I try using gridded(data) <- TRUE it gives me an error saying "dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant". I got stuck there and then tried using autoKrige to get the grid. Am I right in assuming that autoKrige would get me a dataframe that could be converted to a raster image?

Comment: You can use `spsample` to create a grid from a polygon, which you can create e.g. by using a convex hull around the data points.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra..I tried using a convex hull..So the thing is in my original dataset I have a density value associated with each of my 900K points. I want to show this density on a map as grid cells.If I take the convex hull, convert it into a polygon and then sample points from it, I will lose the density information. Is it possible to maybe create a grid independently and then use the values of points lying in a cell to estimate the value for the cell in the grid? I think that would be a better approach.

Comment: And yeah my laptop crashed trying to compute the autoKrige on the data!

Comment: Edit your question to add the additional information. Do note that I do not know what you mean by `lose the density information`. If you simply want to visualise density, you can also calculate the kernel density. See `Point pattern analysis` in http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra..Done. Well it's density in the sense that all points have a specific value associated with them. And I want to plot a heatmap based on these values.